# How to beam 16th notes in 6/4 and 3/2 times?

Tags: theory

Somebody says that 16th notes in time 6/4 should be grouped by four. But if the beat is dotted minim, then I assume they should be grouped by 12.

Which one is correct? I didn't find an example.

Comment: 16th notes in a 6/4 time are  corresponding 32nd notes in a 6/8 time. This is very seldom because music with such small notes can  easily be notated in 3/8 respectively 3/4 time.

Answer (score 1):

In the time signature 6/4, the rules for beaming are the following:

> 1. **Do not beam across a bar line.** All beaming takes place within the measure! If you have a stray eighth note at the end of a measure,
>      it should be written with the tail, rather than connected to the first
>      beat of the next measure.
> 2. **Do not beam across the center of a measure.**
>      These beats are almost always separated to ensure clear rhythm for the
>      reader.
> 3. **Sixteenth Notes are grouped by beat.** For example, in a meter where the quarter note gets a beat, a maximum of four sixteenth notes
>      should be grouped together. If a dotted quarter note gets a beat, a
>      maximum of six sixteenth notes can be grouped together.
> 4. **Thirty-Second Notes are grouped by beat.** For example, in 4/4 time, a maximum of eight thirty-second notes can be grouped together.
>      But because the triple lines of thirty-second note beams can get a
>      little messy, we connect groups of four with a single line."

So answering your question, in 6/4 time signature, sixteenth notes are beamed in 4 notes at a time.

*Source: [this](https://www.musicnotes.com/now/musictheory/note-beaming-and-grouping-in-music-theory/)*

Comment: I'm not necessarily disagreeing with the fact that usually 16th notes are beamed 4 at a time, but your guidelines somewhat contradict this, as #3 says they are grouped by beat.  In 6/4, the dotted half note is the beat, as the OP states.  (Sometimes, in 6/4, 16ths are handled as your #4 guideline suggests for 32nds, i.e., with multiple levels of beaming to indicate primary beats and subdivisions.)

Comment: Rule 2 does not apply to 3/4 time.

Comment: i have rephrashed my answer @phoog

Comment: @Haversine I saw that post, but it did not seem convincing. The first ballad of Chopin has a measure where they are grouped by 4 in a dotted half note beat. It contradicts your reference.

Comment: @prstch Which measure are you talking about? I looked through it and did not find anything....

Comment: @Haversine https://youtu.be/nW5po_Z7YEs?t=148